# How to get a part of text in Selenium and web driver using Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, web-crawler

I want to use Selenium and Web driver to catch a part of information. 
I want to catch the following information:

`7197409`

[image]

The following code is their html code, I want to catch "7197409"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var messageid = 7197409;
  var highlight_id = -1;
  var authorOnly = "N";
  var ftype = 'MB';
  var adsenseFront = '<table width="99%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: #000000; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><tr><td style="width: 100%; background-color: #F7F3F7;">';
  var adsenseEnd = '</td></tr></table>';
  var Submitted = false;
  var subject = true;
  var HiddenThreads = new Array(26); //Temp variable to save the threads temporary
  var blocked_list = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize('[]');
  var currentUser = undefined;
  var followList = [];
  var lock = false;
</script>
```

I checked their full xpath is `/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/script/text()`

I use the following code to execute it.

```
from datetime import date,datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import numpy as np
import xlrd
import csv
import codecs
import time

url = "https://forumd.hkgolden.com/view.aspx?type=MB&message=7197409"
driver_blank=webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver_blank.get(url)
id=driver_blank.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/script/text()")
print("ID:"+id.text)

driver_blank.close()
```

However, I got the following error message. They said that `The result of the xpath expression "/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/script/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.`

> DevTools listening on
>   ws://127.0.0.1:50519/devtools/browser/845d0800-1dd9-4f8a-a847-7d955c8cc5e3
>       libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB
>       [16136:16764:0411/213956.920:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
>       [16136:16764:0411/213957.351:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File ".\test.py", line 28, in 
>           id=driver_blank.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s6d0.png)/script/text()")
>       File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
>           return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
>       File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 978, in find_element
>           'value': value})['value']
>       File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>           self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>       File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>           raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression
>   "/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s6d0.png)/script/text()" is:
>   [object Text]. It should be an element.
>       (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

I want to ask two questions:

1. How to solve the error?
2. How to get only text of 7197409 in same xpath range?

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: try to use css selector and then look for the child you want.

Comment: you need to add some wait preferably a explicit wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the *script* **WebElement**:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_view_form")
script = div.find_element_by_tag_name('script')
```

Get the *script* **InnerHTML**:

```
text = script.get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(text)
```

Find the line containing *"var messageid"*:

```
line = [l for l in text.split("\n") if "var messageid" in l][0]
print("Line:", line)
```

Get the number from the line:

```
ix_1 = line.find("=")
ix_2 = line.find(";")

number = int(line[ix_1+1:ix_2])
print("Number:", number)
```

Out (Tested in Chromium 80.x):

```
Number: 7197409
```